# How to set font family in text box using drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code

```
<html>
   <form method="post" action="Demo7.jsp">
      Select Programming font:
      <select name="font">
         <option value="arial">arial black</option>
         <option value="tohma">ENGLISH</option>
         <option value="times new roman">times new roman</option>
      </select>
      EnterValue: <input type="text" name="text1"><br> 
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
   </form>
</html>
```

I want to use the font I select from  the drop down list.  It should change the textbox and textbox font based on the selected font.

I don't know how to do this.  Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is weird question. do u want to send form to server or not? if yes use template engine to set for example inline style for textbox. or as given below use jquery to set css style on change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('textarea').css('font-family', $(this).val()); //for textarea
    //$('input[type="text"]').css('font-family', $(this).val()); // for textbox
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyuhf/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('select[name="font"]').on('change',function(){
        $('input[name="text1"]').css('font-family',this.value);
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kf3VH/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("select[name='font']").change(function() {
      $("input[name='text1']").css("font-family", $(this).val());

});
```

Comment: You have a missing apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

Add some class for select

And try it

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $('.somefont').change(function(){
        font= $(this).val();
        //Set Font Family for element that you needed.
        $('body').css('font-family', font);
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to use jQuery, you can also due this pretty easily with just plain JavaScript, CSS, and an `onChange` attribute added to your `select` element. Something like:

```
<select name="font" onChange="document.getElementsById('text1').style.fontFamily = this.value;">
  <option value="arial">arial black</option>
  <option value="tahoma">ENGLISH</option>
  <option value="times new roman">times new roman</option>
</select>

EnterValue: <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1"><br>
```

Note that you also need to add an `id` attribute to the text input for this to work.